# Information about API's, Core data iOS design from the start

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Good Morning,

I am in the process of designing an app. It will capture data in the device and will sync with a web server, I have a few months learning Swift to develope iOS apps and I am learning to use core data now with small samples.

I have a book I've been reading and available resources like this one:
https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

My question is:
Do I have to start learning how to sync and save data in the device at the same time? or I can learn Core Data first, make the app and then start the process of syncing (using JSON)?

What available resources can I see to learn what I need?

This is new for me, I have a friend who knows Ruby and has knowledge about API, but he does not know how mobile devices works in this matter.

I have searched here, but a lot of question and answers I see covers specific topics.

Your help and time is really appreciated. Thanks!

P.S.
I apologize for the term sync (send and receive data to/from the server) if I a using it wrong, or should I use the term API? For me is a little confusing on how to use the term, since it is use for a few things, like data, but also it's used when talking about a method which all the info you need to go to the API of the method, function or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process you should follow is first learn basic iOS developemeet. Check out the tutorials at [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com) and [hacking with swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com). In the process you will learn a bit about networking(working with APIs) and Data Persistence(Core Data).

Since collection of data precedes storage of data you must learn first about REST APIs, JSON, JSON parsing and related stuff, third party libraries available like Alamofire and SwiftyJSON(these can be installed using cocoapods) 
And then jump into data persistence which can be done through sqlite database(FMDB is a wrapper available and is super easy), Core Data, NSUserDefaults, plist, Realm etc.

Comment: You've been very helpful. I would like to see what others can add to this.I already passed the basics I believe, I've done a few projects and a Product Catalog on my own with a slide menu using SWRevealViewController. Following your suggestions, then I will go for networking with APIs and Core Data where I am right now, but I was missing Networking.

Comment: For Swift I also liked the Hegarty / Stanford 'Developing iOS 9 Apps with Swift' course, which includes CoreData coverage (prior year's versions don't necessarily).  It's free through iTunes and provides a pretty good start at doing things well, not just getting it to kinda work.

Comment: Yes Dan, I was looking at these videos but I need more foundation, these videos requires previews classes which the instructor say which ones are. I am going back to these when I feel more comfortable to take it, they are excellent. The instructor explains very good and the exercises are awesome.

Comment: By the way, my friend says that data should not be saved in the device, eh says everything should be manage by the API, but I'm asking, I need to save data in order to let the user use the App when is online, and later send the data to the server when a connection is available.

Comment: He isn't wrong in saying that everything should be managed by API. But if you want your app to have offline access then data has to be saved on device. Making your app (just app and not all of its features) offline accessible is a core part of UX. For e.g. chat apps(FB Messenger, whatsapp etc.) Chats should be accessible even if the user can't connect to the internet.